# Can't tap the button if I add UIHostingController as a child (its view opaque is set to false)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, storyboard

### View Hierarchy

1. ViewController
2. HostingViewController

[image] [image]

### Discussion

At `viewDidLoad`'s ViewController, it will add the `UIHostingController` and set the `isOpaque` property to `false` because user can tap the button that is in ViewController.

Unfortunately, I won't able to tap the button

```swift
let ipView = UIHostingController(rootView: InputView())

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    addChild(ipView)
    view.addSubview(ipView.view)

    // It's can't tap the button in ViewController
    // even I set the isOpaque = false
    ipView.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    ipView.view.isOpaque = false
    
    ipView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    ipView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    ipView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    ipView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    ipView.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

The button should be triggered the tapped event, but it's not if I add `UIHostingController`

```swift
@IBAction func buttonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitle("Tapped", for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Comment: Any solution found? @IosAdvocate